# document.getElementById('ID') is it returning null in only part of my code

Tags: javascript, html

I can not get the values ​​from an HTML page using document.getElementById ("ID"),is returning Null, in all the rest of the code everything works perfectly

Something so simple is driving me crazy, because in other parts of the code identically everything works perfectly

HTML:

```
<div id="childTemplateNotice" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="headerNews col-md-12">
        <h1 class="titleNotice"></h1>
        <p class="subTitle"></p>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="date"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function postNotice(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('childTemplateNotice'))
}



HTML INDEX:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-   scale=1.0">
    <title></title>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="notice.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../components/coments/coments.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/reset.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../components/header/header.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../components/footer/footer.css" media="screen" />
<!-- Bootstrap e Jquery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php include "../../components/header/header.html"; ?>

    <div id="noticeFather"class=" col-md-12">  
    <div class="ads col-md-12 top">

</div>

<div class="headerNews col-md-12">
    <h1 class="titleNotice"></h1>
    <p class="subTitle"></p>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="date"></span>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="right col-md-3"></div>

    <div class="midle col-md-6">

    <p class="body"></p>
    <span class="linkTitle"></span>
    <a class="linkUrl"></a>
    <!-- Coments -->
    <div class="comentsDiv col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="left col-md-3"></div>
</div>
</div>    
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<?php include "../../components/coments/coments.html" ?>    
</div>
<?php include "../../components/footer/footer.html"; ?>
</div>
<!-- Scripts js --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../components/header/header.js">       </script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../service/esmiucado-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../repositorio/repositorio.js"> </script>
<!-- Requisição DataBase -->
<script>

    postNotice()
    getComents(noticeCod)    
</script>

</body>
</html>

I already try:

$(document).ready(function() {

    function postNotice(){
        console.log(document.getElementById('childTemplateNotice'))
    }
});

and:
window.onload = function postNotice(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('childTemplateNotice'))
}
```

and they did not work

OBS: the files javascript and html are in different directories

UPDATE:

When I call the function of another page everything works fine, so the problem is when I call this specific page, but I have not yet identified which problem

Comment: Where do you ever call `postNotice()`?  Please provide a complete example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (preferably as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You're *defining* postNotice on document.ready. Is it possible that you're trying to *call* postNotice before document.ready, and that therefore the null is not from the document.getElementById,  it's because postNotice itself isn't defined yet? 
 That's only a guess, since you haven't shown that part of your code; a [mcve] would clear this up.

Comment: Sorry, I put the index.html now

Answer (score 2):

in `document.ready` function either remove the `function` inside it or call the `function`. First one  is also working fine you just have to call the function. `window.onload` is working perfectly

```js
function postNotice(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('childTemplateNotice'))
}
postNotice();

 $(document).ready(function() {

  console.log(document.getElementById('childTemplateNotice'))


});


window.onload = function postNotice(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('childTemplateNotice'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="childTemplateNotice" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="headerNews col-md-12">
        <h1 class="titleNotice"></h1>
        <p class="subTitle"></p>
    <div class="row">
         <span class="date"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: They said `getElementById` was returning null. It couldn't do that if they weren't calling it. There's clearly some important stuff missing from the question. It isn't answerable in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was happening simply because I was not calling the html element on the main page.